# Use a many-parameters function as callback function

Tags: c, function-pointers

I'm using a timer, in C, which is system-dependant (I cannot change its code). I can access it, among others, with this function :

```
void start_timer(int duration, void (*callback)(void*), void* arg);
```

So I can give to the timer a callback function and its `void*` argument.

The function I would like to use as callback is:

```
void send_message(ipaddr* source, ipaddr* destination, char* message);
```

I cannot directly give this function to `start_timer`, because it does not match the `void (*)(void*)` required type. As anonymous functions does not exist in C, I *cannot* use this solution (but it is what I would like to do):

```
start_timer(1000, void(*)(void* stuff){
    send_message(source, destination, message);
}, NULL);
```

So I must give a name to this function:

```
void call_send_message(void* stuff) {
    send_message(source, destination, message);
}
start_timer(1000, &call_send_message, NULL);
```

Is there a more beautiful way to call `send_message` function using `start_timer`?

Comment: In fact, I would like to bypass the wrapper (`call_send_message`) and directly use `send_message` into `start_timer`.

Answer (score 5):

Create a `struct`, something like this:

```
struct args {
    ipaddr *source;
    ipaddr *destination;
    char *message;
};
```

and have your `send_message` function take `void*` argument, then you just cast it to a `struct args` type and from there you can access its members. If you can't edit it, then create a "wrapper" like your example:

So basically your function below

```
void call_send_message(void* stuff) {
    send_message(source, destination, message);
}
```

becomes

```
void call_send_message(void* stuff) {
    struct args *realstuff = (struct args *) stuff;
    send_message(realstuff->source, realstuff->destination, realstuff->message);
}
```

Comment: This answer explains how to pass the `source`, `destination` and `message` variables, from the caller of `start_timer`, to the `send_message` function. The question supposes that they are accessible globally.

Comment: @ryolait If they are globals then you don't even need the arguments. If you do;Just create a struct with several pointer-to-pointer that points to your global variables and voilah you can still send it as one argument in a .... `struct`.

Comment: I cannot edit the `send_message` function, and this function works only with its parameters, not with global ones. However, when I set the timer, I suppose variables are accessible. The problem is that the `void*` parameter does not correspond with the `(ipaddr*, ipaddr*, char*)` parameters. The three parameters use more space into the call stack than a pointer, so I must use a wrapper.

Comment: @ryolait So just do it as in my answer? Is there a problem with doing it that way?

Comment: In my personal situation, I do not even need to use the structure. My question was about not using a wrapper, which is impossible given the function prototypes. However, I agree that, in a situation where passing parameters to the wrapper function is a problem, your answer (and the 101010's one) is correct the solution.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Make a data structure to store your data.

```
typedef struct Data {
  ipaddr *src;
  ipaddr *dst;
  char   *msg;
} Data;
```

### 2. Make a wrapper that matches the signature and call inside the `send_message` function:

```
void wrapper(void *args) {
  Data *data = (Data*) args;
  send_message(data->src, data->dst, data->msg);

}
```

### 3. Call wrapper like below:

```
   start_timer(duration, &wrapper, your_data);
```

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted but your example requires a `typedef` for the struct

Comment: This is almost the same answer as Jite one: it explains how to pass the `source`, `destination` and `message` variables, from the caller of `start_timer`, to the `send_message` function. The question supposes that they are accessible globally.

Answer (score 0):

`void*` is a type that describe a pointer to a variable we don't know the type. You cannot dereference it, but you can cast it into a pointer to any type (`char*`, `int*`, `mydata*`…). If `send_message` takes only one parameter which is a pointer (of any type), you do not need any wrapper:

```
void send_message(char* message); // only one pointer parameter

char* my_string = ...;
start_timer(1000, send_message, (void*)my_string);
```

However, you must use a wrapper if `send_message` takes more than one parameter, because the arguments taken by `send_message` (here, three pointers) are definitively different than the one given by `start_timer` (one pointer). The size taken into the stack is not the same, so this may not work.

See others answers to know how to pass the parameters in this situation.

**Edit**:
In fact, you might do without wrapper if the parameter(s) taken by `send_message` have exactly the same size than a pointer. If the pointer is 4 bytes length, and if `send_message` had taken 4 `char` variables, you could hack the system, by making your four bytes as a fake `void*` pointer. However, this is particularly ugly, and I recommend you use a wrapper in this situation.

Comment: Are you answering your own question? If you can edit the `send_message` function then yes you _could_ abuse it like you describe, but that potentially introduces other issues, do **not** do that unless you know exactly what your doing (you can easily end up with endiness problems for instance). You **don't** need a wrapper if you can edit the `send_message` function, just make it take a `struct` as argument and you are home.

Comment: Yes, I answer my own question, after having speak about it with my colleagues. If I cannot edit the `send_message` prototype, I must use a wrapper. If I can edit this prototype, I can use a **pointer** to a `struct` as argument (a `struct` only is incorrect, because of the different size).